# Which Block cipher mode should I use?

Tags: block-cipher, modes-of-operation

Which of the Block cipher mode is **MOST** secure? I dont care about the performance just the **most** secure

Comment: Define "secure".

Comment: Define "secure": Something thats not/less vulnerable for attacks

Comment: The best choice of block cipher mode depends on context. Apart from ECB all popular modes are semantically secure. But perhaps you need integrity checks, in which case you might want authenticated encryption, like AES-GCM or a traditional MAC in an encrypt-then-mac scheme. Sometimes you need to preserve the length, sometimes you need nonce reuse resistance, sometimes you need asymmetric authentication, sometimes you worry about certain side-channels, sometimes you don't...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of secure. What most experts agree on is that ECB is a bad idea. The wiki page actually provides a pretty solid overview http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation